# Fixed navigation div (no height) without overlap

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to `position: fixed;` a navigation bar at the top of the page (no scrolling), but the first div below is overlapping (see http://jsfiddle.net/sexyzane/c0wop7vn/ : you can't see the first row of content).

I know the "classic" solution, but I **can't neither force the height of the element**, nor use a pixel-based margin (or padding). Javascript is not an option (I need pure CSS or HTML).

I can't believe is so hard to say "stay at the top, no matter your height, everything else should follow below"...

Comment: This is simply not possible without JS or adding a margin/padding to off set it from the top. A fixed position element is out of the flow of the document so it's ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to duplicate the fixed header and use a different css class? If so you could create a copy of the div that's hidden but still taking up space behind the fixed one. Upon scrolling it might look weird but I'm not sure you have many other options.

```
<div class="fixed-header">I'm fixed at the top!</div>
<div class="header-hidden">I'm fixed at the top!</div>
<div class="main-content">
    text row 1 text row 1 text row 1 text row 1 text row 1 text row 1
    <br>text row 2text row 2text row 2text row 2text row 2text row 2text row 2text row 2
    <br>text row 3text row 3text row 3text row 3text row 3text row 3text row 3text row 3
</div>
```

With this css (note the `position: relative` and `visibility:hidden` on the new class):

```
.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: fuchsia;
    width: 100%;
}
.header-hidden {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: fuchsia;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
main-content {
    background-color: fuchsia;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: green;
}
```